# Import a dataset from figshare to google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a large dataset in figshare website, and I want to use it for training a deep learning model in google colab. Because of amount of data I can not download it and upload it again in google drive. Is there any way to load data from figshare into google colab directly or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wget to download it directly.

For example, from this page

https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/gene_expression_matrix/13011164

You can get the download link and call wget

```
!wget --content-disposition https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/24792068
```

The data is then downloaded.

Comment: What should I do next? the downloaded file format is not specified. it is not zip or other formats!

Comment: @Mohadese What's your figshare URL?

Comment: there is no difference for me. I checked the URL you sent, but it has a similar problem.

Comment: I add --content-disposition which will help with file format problem.